# Rx Observable on value types

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

I have an API receiving messages as structs in a callback method

```
void OnReceive(ref T message)
```

. That method receives those struct objects by reference to avoid copy. I am thinking to wrap that API and expose messages as observable.

Given that I can't make an observable of struct references and that the structs are passed/returned by making a copy that solution

```
Observable<T> GetItems() //where T is struct
```

seems to be pretty suboptimal and it is better to keep using callback approach all the way through. Is there a better way to deal with structs in Rx extension library?

Comment: How large are your structs ? Usually structs should be small objects with a small amount of data. Larger data structures should be modeled as classes instead. Put another way, my initial feeling is that you are concerned with premature optimizations or you should redesign and use a class instead.

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct) for more on that

Comment: @EnricoMassone, the choice of using structs was dictated by the underlying API that deals with lower level “unmanaged” serialization. Those structs have 20-30 fields, so the size is too significant to ignore. Writing a class  DTO feels overkill.

Comment: Just to better understand your point, the main concern you have now is that by creating an observable sequence, you will endup copying the struct instances ? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @EnricoMassone, correct. The concern is that every “select”, “where” and “subscribe” callbacks will end up copying structs multiple times per message.

Comment: Could you not simply wrap the value type in a class and have the observable pass the class? Something like this: `public class Ref<T> where T : struct { public T Value { get; init; } }`. Then you only have one copy made and after that it's just copying the reference.

Comment: @ddv - Please respond to my above comment.

Comment: yeah, I think that is a very viable solution here. Thanks @Enigmativity

Comment: Only profiling the code would prove or debunk any of the hypothesis regarding performance. Giving a recomendation saying, use a struct only if "It has an instance size under 16 bytes" sounds like we are executing on a 8085 CPU and about at the same time. :) You may want to actually profile a `SomeClass<T>` vs a struct `T` - including tracing side effects of the garbage collector. I would bet, it will not matter anyway - given you load the data from an API anyway which may count for 99.99% of the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply wrap the value type in a class and have the observable pass the class.

Something like this:

```
public class Ref<T> where T : struct { public T Value { get; init; } }
```